# Why OnClickListener of ListView items in Navigation Drawer never fires?

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, onitemclicklistener

I'm creating an Android app with Navigation Drawer.

I faced a problem with `OnItemClickListener`, somehow can't get it fire at all.

**All items comes to `ListView` correctly, but never fires any actions.**

I set `OnItemClickListener` as Android Developer page suggests, without any luck.

**MainActivity.java**

```
Private ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    listView = (ListView)activity.findViewById(R.id.navigationList);
    setItems(listView);
}

private void setItems(ListView listView) {
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        boolean bSelected = false;
        if(i==selected) {
            bSelected = true;
        }
        adapter = new DrawerAdapter(context, generateData(items, i, titles[i], subtitles[i], subTexts[i], icons[i], bottomDivider[i], bSelected), layout);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());


    listView.invalidate();
    listView.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
}



private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // THIS NEVER FIRES!!!
        Toast.makeText(context, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I use almost the same code on other part of my application to show messages etc, and `OnItemClickListener` works correctly on other places.

```
private ArrayList<DrawerRow> generateData(ArrayList<DrawerRow> items, int id, String title, String subtitle, String subText, int icon, boolean bottomDivider, boolean bSelected) {
    items.add(new DrawerRow(id, title, subtitle, subText, icon, bottomDivider, bSelected));
    return items;
}
```

What part is wrong, or do I need to do totally differently?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:focusable="false"` on your XML for the `ListView` and on the root element of Drawer item layout